# Pyqt5 : dynamically change label value, with no clicking signal

Tags: qgis, python, pyqgis, qgis-plugins, pyqt5

I have a question regarding PyQGIS.

I am currently developing a plugin, and I wish to update a window's label as soon as the window opens, without having to click on a button.

Here is what I do: I open my plugin, and when clicking on a button, it opens a second window. On that window, I have a label with a default value (that value comes from the ui file, created with QtCreator).
The goal is, as soon as the window opens, to check another class attribute. If that attribute has a value, the label must be updated with that value. If the class attribute is 'None', then the label keeps the default value.
I must not click on a button, or hover the text. However, I did not find any sort of signal allowing to check a label when a window opens.

I tried calling a method directly in the attribute definition, but it does not work:

```
class MySecondWindow(QtWidgets.QDialog, FORM_CLASS):
    def __init__(self, myInput, parent=None):
        super(MySecondWindow, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setupUi(self)

        self.myInfoClass = myInput
        self.myData = self.dynamicallyChangeLabel()
        self.dynamicallyChangeLabel()

    def dynamicallyChangeLabel(self):
        print("Checking label value")
        if self.myInfoClass.myInfoAttribute != None :
            self.myLabel.setText(self.myInfoClass.myInfoAttribute)
```

It seems the `dynamicallyChangeLabel` is not even called, since there is no print in my console.

Does anyone have an idea how to do this?

Comment: Is the `self.myInfoClass.myInfoAttribute` variable entered by the user through the plugin window?
If yes, you can connect the input event to the label update.

Answer (score 1):

In the end I used the *showEvent* method : it is called right away, without waiting for a user action.

```
def showEvent(self,showEvent):
        self.fillComboBox()
```

It is very useful !